# Serving "Profiled" Component Presentations Over CD Webservice

Tags: content-delivery

**Profiling and personalization (PnP or "WAI") allows authors the ability to set Component Presentations for certain Target Groups**. CD-side controls or tags then present the correct Component Presentations based on the user's profile.

**Does PnP work over the CD Webservice?**

If PnP is better suited for .aspx / .jsp "setups" would these be better alternatives for "profiling over OData (CD Webservice)?"

1. **Ambient Data Framework?** Following [Eric Huiza's ADF-in-a-nutshell post](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2012/07/ambient-data-framework-in-nutshell.html), I think we might use claims. Would using ADF make sense to influence the Component Presentations based on metadata in the components matching a given visitor "type?"
2. **REL logic**. In the recent [SDL Tridion community webinar](http://webinars.julianwraith.com/2013/07/31/september-2013-webinar/), Mihai Cadariu explained how his [REL Standard Library](http://yatb.mitza.net/2013/07/rel-standard-tag-library.html) can offer if/else type logic. I can see how this could be used to show certain content to different (types of) users but I'm not sure how the delivery website would pass this information to the CD Webservice.
3. **Deliver-side "parsing"** where delivery-side code gets a full page and parses it to show hide certain content.

**Use case:** in a CD Webservice request, get back certain component presentations based on component metadata (or Target Groups if possible?); in this case the roles might be "secured" content versus "not secured."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PnP relies on the current Web Context, so that it can access to the user context information, the cd web service runs in a different context than the web application or at least in a different request, Having said that I would say your solution would be a combination of REL tags and ADF.

For instance in Tridion 2013 you can pass claims to the CD Web Service (ADF part), also you can access to those claims in REL tags (REL part) that are executed by the CD Web Service.

Here the implementation area. In the regular PnP implementation we have JSTL tags or ASP .Net Web Controls to execute Target Groups / Tracking logic, you will need to implement a Target Group / Tracking REL tag.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, this covers enough for implementation to consider. +1 and accepted. We'll avoid scenarios like multiple pages (one per profile) or parsing the component presentation text in delivery. :-)